# Ionic 4 How to change segment on click

Tags: ionic4

I need to know how can i change the segment by click on button ? I try with ngModel but its showing error ngModel cant bind with ion-segment. Then I import FormModule in app.module.ts But still same error. Can any one please tell how can i change the segment button on click ? Thanks

```
  <ion-segment value="javascript">
      <ion-segment-button value="python">
        <ion-label>Python</ion-label>
      </ion-segment-button>
      <ion-segment-button value="javascript">
        <ion-label>Javascript</ion-label>
      </ion-segment-button>
    </ion-segment>
    <button (click)="next()></button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be using ion-segment incorrectly. You need to add in the ionChange event to the ion-segment. Follow the Ionic Docs for ion-segment: https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/segment.

Here's an example:

**In your HTML file:**

```
<ion-segment (ionChange)="segmentChanged($event)" [(ngModel)]="segment">
  <ion-segment-button value="first">
    <ion-label>First</ion-label>
  </ion-segment-button>
  <ion-segment-button value="second">
    <ion-label>Second</ion-label>
  </ion-segment-button>
</ion-segment>
```

**In your typescript:**

```
export class Example {
  segment = "segment value";

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {}

  segmentChanged(ev: any) {
    // Add your logic here
  }
}
```

Comment: Already try with this as mention but there probelm is showing error of [(ngModel)] cant bind

Comment: In your example you don't have an [(ngModel)], nor ionClick. Could you show me exactly how you have your HTML and ts?